# How should keyboard mnemonics be localized?

Tags: c#, java, c++, localization, internationalization

Is there a standard approach to localizing (internationalize) keyboard mnemonics? For example, in Windows Explorer (English), if the user types Alt-F then C, the File menu opens and then the Close operation is selected.

For a language using qwerty, I guess you can change the mnemonic letters depending on the translated words. But what about a language like Chinese? I've seen some programs put the mnemonic after label in parenthesis, but it doesn't seem ideal.

**Reposted:** https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39074/how-should-keyboard-mnemonics-be-localized

Comment: This question would be better posted on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah didn't know that existed ... is it bad form to post again there?

Comment: @PeterTseng Yeah, if you want to move your question there, flag it for moderator attention and explain that you want to move it there.

Comment: Got it, Thanks. I don't really like how UX is a separate site though.

Answer (score 0):

With Java, you can use [ResouceBundles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html). With them, you can create files that hold, each one, strings and objects for a certain locale. For example, you write Resource Bundles for `en`, `en_US`, `en_UK`.

Let's say `en_US` is the default for English. You write `en` as if it where `en_US`, leave `en_US` blank and just write differences between `en_US` and `en_UK` in the `en_UK` file, Java will find the "equals" in the default `en` file.

[This presentation](http://www.unicode.org/iuc/iuc15/ta4/slides.pdf) will introduce some of the concepts of Java i18n.

Comment: Yeah, we do use ResourceBundles and property files already (we use Java, but this isn't really a Java-specific problem). That presentation was also informative, but no mention of mnemonics.

Comment: Well, `ResourceBundle` store an array of `Object`s. The method `getString()` is a shortcut for `(String) getObject()`. You can store objects that represent a mnemonic that will be put on the component. I didn't get your question was not about "how to/what tools to use to i18n", but a question about the user interface itself. Sorry for my misunderstanding.